# Free up space problem

Tags: google-play-store, sd-card, insufficient-memory, downloading

My android device is lava v2s. I have sufficient space of 5.67 GB on my SD card and even of 263mb but, still, when I want to download any app from Google Play Store, it is saying to free up space. It's really very much disappointing. please try to solve my problem and give me a quick solution.

Comment: For some background on your issue, please see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info). In short, it doesn't matter how much free space you have elsewhere (e.g. on your SD card), it's just about your internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to your settings, find "Storage", then set your default storage to "SD Card", if you still have problems download a new version of Google Play from

Comment: As long as the internal storage is not "cleaned", this won't help either (though it might be helpful after the cleaning to keep the issue from reappearing too fast). For details, please see our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), as I pointed out in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Move part of data on the phone to SD card in settings, or you can delete some useless data on the phone to get more space to install app.

Answer (score 0):

Go To Application Manager From Settings and move your apps to External Storage (Some Apps Are Not Supporting This Feature)
Try To Disbale And Clear Data Apps Which You Don't Use And Bloatwares.